# Double process in linux script

Tags: shell, ubuntu, unix, scripting, centos

Can someone help me understand why if I launch my script, it results in two active processes?

```
$ ps -ef | grep pong
adminus+    3024    2923  0 10:25 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./pong.sh
adminus+    3029    3024  0 10:25 pts/0    00:00:00 /bin/bash ./pong.sh`
```

This is my script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
DIR=/var/tmp/ping-pong
if [ -d $DIR ]
then
    echo "Directory Exists"
else
    mkdir -p $DIR
fi

ping google.it | while read pong; do echo "$(date): $pong" >> $DIR/google-ping-$(date +%d-%m-%Y).txt; done`
```

thank you

Comment: Please click [edit] and format your code properly. Remove all the quotes and bacticks then select your code with the mouse and click `{}` in the Formatting Toolbar beside **Bold** and *Italic* to format as code. Thanks. Or just indent code with 4 spaces.

Comment: Please show how you started it. And show the output. And state your OS. And run your code through https://www.spellcheck.net to remove the errors. And consider whether you want the output filename to potentially change part way through.

Comment: i start it with ./pong &
my OS is: centOS 8
no errors in the code